# ASP.NET MVC show collection of data in View inside of TextArea

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I access data with:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {

        //IEnumerable<ChatLogs> c = from p in db.ChatLogs select p;
        //return View(c);
        using (var db = new ChatLogContext())
        {
            var list = db.ChatLogs.ToList();

            return View(list);

        }

    }
```

I would like to know how to save this collection of data inside of TextArea in View? When we used webforms we could just textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "some data from database";

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Chat.Models.ChatLogs>
@Html.TextArea("chatScreen", new { @Class = "chatScreen" })
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.textarea.aspx)

Comment: why you don't use @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.entry) ?

Comment: Amir you can't because I am retrieving whole collection. I want to write 20 rows of data for example into TextArea.. Not just one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you create a view model. For example:

```
class ChatLogsViewModel
{
    public string LogListString { get; set; }
}
```

Pass that to the view, instead of passing the raw list:

```
var list = db.ChatLogs.ToList();
var vm = new ChatLogsViewModel { LogListString = /* convert list to single string here */ };
return View(vm);
```

And in the view, just do something like this:

```
@model Your.Namespace.ChatLogsViewModel
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.LogListString)
```

Using view models will make your life easier as soon as you decide that you want to pass more information to the view than what a single domain model can carry.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me an advice how to properly convert list to single string? Since if I use `string.Join(", ", list)` I just get multiple times of `Chat.Models.ChatLogs` . I am beginner.

Comment: @JohnMathilda This is because currently, the `ToString()` method of `ChatLogs` defaults to the class name. To fix this, override `ToString()` in `ChatLogs` with the data you want it to show. (What that data is exactly depends on what your class contains and how it stores it, but that part should be very straightforward.)

Comment: Thank you, I did it with your help. Let me ask you, is this the best practice to "pass" data from model, through controller to view? Thank you for viewmodel explanation, I read about it and now I understand the point.

By the way, I don't know if you use it, but what happens if you use ChatLogsViewModel for strong type view usage for example in our case to show this data and if you have the form for submit at the same time in same view. What should I do then? Only jQuery? You know, if you want to use strong type for ChatLogsView and ChatLogs(for form submission fields)? Thank you sir.

Comment: @JohnMathilda It is definitely not a bad practice to pass the domain model (the thing that describes the problem you're solving) to the view, but I've found that passing a view model solved many of my problems effortlessly. It's not necessarily the best practice, but a different good practice.

Comment: @JohnMathilda Regarding submitting forms, I don't think you'll have to change anything. The strong typing of the view applies only for passing data from the controller to the view. When POSTed, the forms will still pass all the data they contain and (as far as I know) the model binder will still try to map that data to the type that your POST action expects. So, I don't think you'll have to change those methods in any way just because you changed the model or resort in jQuery for the POST requests.

Comment: Oh I understand now. I can add additional attribute like `public string Message {get; set;}` to my NEW ViewModel that you suggested, and then use that additional attribute I added for submitting the form in the same view(like `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message)`. I am talking about accessing this stuff. Now I got it. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

In you `.cshtml` view, you can access data using `@Model`

Now, since you have a list, I'd recommend you `join` it and then assign it to `TextArea` like

```
@{var strList = string.Join(" ", Model)}
@Html.TextArea("myTextArea",strList)
```

Comment: I got this into my TextArea : Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs Chat.Models.ChatLogs

Comment: How about you try `strList.toString()`

Comment: I get this System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Chat.Models.ChatLogs] if I use `strList.toString()`

Comment: Can you please post structure of your model `ChatLogs`? I was under impression that it is simple string but it appears not to be.

Comment: No no, it's not the string, it is a model for data with ChatId, Message and UserId. Mister Theodoros Chatzigiannak above told me to override ToString() method in my model class to get data instead of class name "Chat.Models.ChatLogs" if you understand me what I want to say.